# Show Taxonomy Terms belonging to search_api search result nodes

Tags: views, search

Using search_api (and search_api_solr) i have a view that shows nodes for (in this case) Organisations in a search_view. That works very nicely.

Now, I would like to show a list of taxonomy terms that are associated with the nodes in the result set. These terms should be in a list of their own, and I need to be able to access the fields on these terms. (In this case, Districts is the Vocabulary, and each organisation can be active in 1 or more Districts. I need to get to the Geofield on these Districts so I can create an Openlayers map).

When I add a Relationship to the search_view to the District field, I see the message

"Note: This is a multi-valued relationship, which is currently not supported. Only the first related entity will be shown."

So, that is not the way (yet).

I am stuck thinking about a workaround for this. Any pointer would be much appreciated.

Comment: You could maybe export the view and thus add your own code to grab the data you need from related values which views lets you call?

Comment: can you make another view and then use https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view to get the multiple values pulled in?

Answer (score 0):

This may have drawbacks but I had a situation where i wanted to show the multiple tags that related to content that i had indexed.

Having looked through https://www.drupal.org/node/1378656 i opted to try by using https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view

Happy to report it worked

Here is the recipe:

- create a new View based on Content for types involved and set just the relevant 'term' field as the display (you don't need to create any views displays).
- set Contextual filter to nid with 'provided default value = raw value from url' (outcome should be if you enter the nid you should see relevant tags in preview). Save
- install/enable https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view
- over in the view that is rendering the search results (searchapi)
- made sure you have Indexed Content: Node ID field already in your Fields, and set to not display
- add a new field of type Global: View
- in the 'view settings' of this field, find the view you made above, set the right display or use Master if you didn't make any (because you didn't need to),
- in Contextual Filter, check your Replacement Patterns where you should have [%nid] == Indexed Content: Node ID (rendered), and enter [%nid]
- save and I hope you get to smile like i just did.